# Two-dimensional array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I get so confused about 2D arrays in Swift. Let me describe step by step. And would you please correct me if I am wrong.

First of all; declaration of an empty array:

```
class test{
    var my2Darr = Int[][]()
}
```

Secondly fill the array. (such as `my2Darr[i][j] = 0` where i, j are for-loop variables)

```
class test {
    var my2Darr = Int[][]()
    init() {
        for(var i:Int=0;i<10;i++) {
            for(var j:Int=0;j<10;j++) {
                my2Darr[i][j]=18   /*  Is this correct?  */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Lastly, Editing element of in array

```
class test {
    var my2Darr = Int[][]()
    init() {
        ....  //same as up code
    }
    func edit(number:Int,index:Int){
        my2Darr[index][index] = number
        // Is this correct? and What if index is bigger
        // than i or j... Can we control that like 
        if (my2Darr[i][j] == nil) { ...  }   */
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you having problems with your approach?

Comment: Just so you know, your entire second step can be reduced down to this `var my2DArray = Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: 18))` And you should really upgrade to a newer beta. `Int[][]()` is no longer valid syntax. It's been changed to `[[Int]]()`.

Comment: The 2D init using repeated values won't work.  All the rows will point to the same sub-array, and thus no be uniquely writable.

Comment: I wrap a multidimensional array in a new struct for a better API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Swift 5.5**

> It's just to understand how the 2D array can be mounted

[image]

```
import UIKit

var greeting = "Hello, playground"

var arrXY = [[String]]()

//             0   1   2   3
arrXY.append(["A","B","C","D"]) // 0
arrXY.append(["E","F","G","H"]) // 1
arrXY.append(["J","K","L","M"]) // 2
arrXY.append(["N","O","P","Q"]) // 3

print(arrXY)

print(arrXY[2][1]) // xy(2,1)
print(arrXY[0][3]) // xy(0,3)
print(arrXY[3][3]) // xy(3,3)
```

Answer (score 279):

### Define mutable array

```
// 2 dimensional array of arrays of Ints 
var arr = [[Int]]()
```

OR:

```
// 2 dimensional array of arrays of Ints 
var arr: [[Int]] = []
```

OR if you need an array of predefined size (as mentioned by @0x7fffffff in comments):

```
// 2 dimensional array of arrays of Ints set to 0. Arrays size is 10x5
var arr = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: Array(count: 2, repeatedValue: 0))

// ...and for Swift 3+:
var arr = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 2), count: 3)
```

### Change element at position

```
arr[0][1] = 18
```

OR

```
let myVar = 18
arr[0][1] = myVar
```

### Change sub array

```
arr[1] = [123, 456, 789]
```

OR

```
arr[0] += 234
```

OR

```
arr[0] += [345, 678]
```

If you had 3x2 array of 0(zeros) before these changes, now you have:

```
[
  [0, 0, 234, 345, 678], // 5 elements!
  [123, 456, 789],
  [0, 0]
]
```

So be aware that sub arrays are mutable and you can redefine initial array that represented matrix.

### Examine size/bounds before access

```
let a = 0
let b = 1

if arr.count > a && arr[a].count > b {
    println(arr[a][b])
}
```

**Remarks:**
Same markup rules for 3 and N dimensional arrays.

Comment: ok one dumy question: how we assign that array, In C we do like that: arr[i][j]=myVar; but in swift when i try to do same way I got this error " '[([(Int)])].Type' does not have a member named 'subscript' "

Comment: If you have `arr` defined as in the answer then `myVar` should be Int, is it?

Comment: yes it is int. And thank you very much for detailed answer.. now its clear:D

Comment: Trying to figure out if I need to add anything else to the answer... Does latest update to the answer clarify what you've asked in the comment?

Comment: Just a note, with Swift 3 the initialization has changed a little.  The init call is now init(repeating:count:).

Comment: In Swift 3, for copy pasters: `var arr = Int(repeating: Int(repeating: 0, count: 2), count: 3)`

Comment: In Swift 4: `var arr = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 2), count: 3)`

Comment: In Swift 4.2:  for example,3 row, 2 column,  3 * 2 `var arr = Array(count: 2, repeatedValue: Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: 0))`

Comment: You may want to use ContiguousArray rather than Array. Array may give you an ordered list, not quite what you are expecting of an array type. From Apple's doc: "The ContiguousArray type is a specialized array that always stores its elements in a contiguous region of memory. This contrasts with Array, which can store its elements in either a contiguous region of memory or an NSArray instance if its Element type is a class or @objc protocol."

Comment: in swift 5 they flip flopped the arugments it is `Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 2), count: 3)`

Comment: If I create a 2D array using the first two approaches shown here, I get Index out of bounds error when I try to initialize the array with values. See here for a demo - https://swiftfiddle.com/366p4taxtnf23md7qispb3nyaq. Other approaches do work. I wish there would have been a way to specify the size in the first two approaches you mentioned.

Answer (score 30):

From the docs:

You can create multidimensional arrays by nesting pairs of square brackets, where the name of the base type of the elements is contained in the innermost pair of square brackets. For example, you can create a three-dimensional array of integers using three sets of square brackets:

```
var array3D: [[[Int]]] = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

When accessing the elements in a multidimensional array, the left-most subscript index refers to the element at that index in the outermost array. The next subscript index to the right refers to the element at that index in the array that’s nested one level in. And so on. This means that in the example above, array3D[0] refers to [[1, 2], [3, 4]], array3D[0][1] refers to [3, 4], and array3D[0][1][1] refers to the value 4.

Answer (score 28):

Make it Generic **Swift 4**

```
struct Matrix<T> {
    let rows: Int, columns: Int
    var grid: [T]
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int,defaultValue: T) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(repeating: defaultValue, count: rows * columns) as! [T]
    }
    func indexIsValid(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
    }
    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> T {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            return grid[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}


var matrix:Matrix<Bool> = Matrix(rows: 1000, columns: 1000,defaultValue:false)

matrix[0,10] = true


print(matrix[0,10])
```

Comment: I adapted your answer to create a 2D toroidal array. Thanks a lot! https://gist.github.com/amiantos/bb0f313da1ee686f4f69b8b44f3cd184

Comment: Useful but no need to forced cast of `[T]` it could be removed  `as! [T]`

Comment: Here are some thoughts. Would it be worthwhile to make this conform to `RandomAccessCollection` or is it enough just to access the underlying `grid` member? Is this a better fit for `precondition` instead of `assert`? I don't think you need the cast: `as! [T]`

Answer (score 22):

You should be careful when you're using `Array(repeating: Array(repeating: {value}, count: 80), count: 24)`.

If the value is an object, which is initialized by `MyClass()`, then they will use the same reference.

`Array(repeating: Array(repeating: MyClass(), count: 80), count: 24)` doesn't create a new instance of `MyClass` in each array element. This method only creates `MyClass` once and puts it into the array.

Here's a safe way to initialize a multidimensional array.

```
private var matrix: [[MyClass]] = MyClass.newMatrix()

private static func newMatrix() -> [[MyClass]] {
    var matrix: [[MyClass]] = []

    for i in 0...23 {
        matrix.append( [] )

        for _ in 0...79 {
            matrix[i].append( MyClass() )
        }
    }

    return matrix
}
```

Comment: Hi can we improve that as an extension with "anyObject" type?

Comment: Good point about the problem with reference types. However, why do you write `Array(repeating: {value}, could 80)` with braces around `{value}`? That would create an array of closures, would it not?

Comment: Or is `{value}` meta-notation for "some value of type AnyObject" (a reference type)?

Comment: I spent almost an hour looking for a bug because of this problem...

Answer (score 18):

**In Swift 4**

```
var arr = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 2), count: 3)
// [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 14):

According to Apple documents for swift 4.1 you can use this struct so easily to create a 2D array:

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html

Code sample:

```
struct Matrix {
    let rows: Int, columns: Int
    var grid: [Double]
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: rows * columns)
    }
    func indexIsValid(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
    }
    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Double {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            return grid[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it. It's reminiscent of C pointer arithmetic. It would be better if rewritten using Generics though, so it would apply to 2-dimensional arrays of any data type. For that matter, you could use this approach to create arrays any arbitrary dimension.

Comment: @vacawama, cool, except your n-dimensional array has the same problem as all the solutions that populate the array using `Array(repeating:count:)`. See the comment I posted to your other answer.

Answer (score 7):

Before using multidimensional arrays in Swift, **consider their impact on performance**. In my tests, the flattened array performed almost 2x better than the 2D version:

```
var table = [Int](repeating: 0, count: size * size)
let array = [Int](1...size)
for row in 0..<size {
    for column in 0..<size {
        let val = array[row] * array[column]
        // assign
        table[row * size + column] = val
    }
}
```

**Average execution time for filling up a 50x50 Array: 82.9ms**

vs.

```
var table = [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: size), count: size)
let array = [Int](1...size)
for row in 0..<size {
    for column in 0..<size {
        // assign
        table[row][column] = val
    }
}
```

**Average execution time for filling up a 50x50 2D Array: 135ms**

Both algorithms are O(n^2), so the difference in execution times is caused by the way we initialize the table.

Finally, the **worst** you can do is using `append()` to add new elements. That proved to be the slowest in my tests:

```
var table = [Int]()    
let array = [Int](1...size)
for row in 0..<size {
    for column in 0..<size {
        table.append(val)
    }
}
```

**Average execution time for filling up a 50x50 Array using append(): 2.59s**

### Conclusion

Avoid multidimensional arrays and use access by index if execution speed matters. 1D arrays are more performant, but your code might be a bit harder to understand.

You can run the performance tests yourself after downloading the demo project from my GitHub repo: https://github.com/nyisztor/swift-algorithms/tree/master/big-o-src/Big-O.playground

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in one simple line.

**Swift 5**

```
var my2DArray = (0..<4).map { _ in Array(0..<) }
```

You could also map it to instances of any class or struct of your choice

```
struct MyStructCouldBeAClass {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

var my2DArray: [[MyStructCouldBeAClass]] = (0..<2).map { x in
    Array(0..<2).map { MyStructCouldBeAClass(x: x, y: $0)}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean: var my2DArray = (0..<4).map { _ in Array(0..<4) }. ?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift version 5.5**

This version uses an underlying array of optionals to avoid runtime surprises that would be caused by the use of assertions.

```swift
struct Matrix<T> {
  let numberOfRows: Int
  let numberOfColumns: Int
  
  var elements: [T?]
  
  /// Creates a new matrix whose size is defined by the specified number of rows and columns.
  /// containing a single, repeated optional value.
  ///
  ///  - Parameters:
  ///    - repeatedValue: The element to repeat
  ///    - numberOfRows: The number of rows
  ///    - numberOfColumns: The number of columns
  init(repeating repeatedValue: T? = nil, numberOfRows: Int, numberOfColumns: Int) {
    // counts must be zero or greater.
    let numberOfRows = numberOfRows > 0 ? numberOfRows : 0
    let numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns > 0 ? numberOfColumns : 0
    
    self.numberOfRows = numberOfRows
    self.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns
    self.elements = Array(repeating: repeatedValue, count: numberOfRows * numberOfColumns)
  }
  
  subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> T? {
    get { elements[(row * numberOfColumns) + column] }
    set { elements[(row * numberOfColumns) + column] = newValue }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a 1D array and just index it separately. For example consider using:

```
struct MatrixIndexer {
    var rows: Int
    var columns: Int
    
    var count: Int {
        return rows * columns
    }
    
    subscript(_ r: Int, _ c: Int) -> Int {
        precondition(r < rows && c < columns)
        return r * columns + c
    }
    
    func coordinate(_ i: Int) -> (row: Int, column: Int) {
        precondition(i < count)
        return (i / columns, i % columns)
    }
}

let at = MatrixIndexer(rows: 16, columns: 8)
var array2D: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0, count: at.count)

array2D[at[3, 4]] = 3
array2D[at[5, 2]] = 6
```

(If you want a single struct to pass around, you could introduce an `Array2D` which contains the `MatrixIndexer` and an `Array`).

Why is this a good idea? First, you get nicer operations out of the box such as:

- Collection extensions: map, filter, reduce
- iterate all elements in a singe loop
- easy copying
- Ensure the invariant that each row and column is the same size

Second, it is also much better for performance.

- Faster access time by reducing memory allocation. Each element is contiguous with the next, instead of each row being a separate point off in memory.
- Use one allocation and deallocation command instead of many (allocators are often slow for a variety of reasons)

Comment: Shouldn't `m.count` be `at.count` in the above example?  Otherwise, what is `m`?

Comment: @jsbox You are correct. It is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It can sometimes help to make things simpler if you use a `typealias` for the underlying array type. Here is an example for a 2D array of `String`:

```swift
typealias Strings = [String]

let stringGroups: [Strings] // aka [[String]]
```