# Data structure for bidimensional array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, data-modeling

I have an array of string arrays.
it has to be declared empty, and it's later filled one array at a time.

I have tried any possible data structure, but none of them seems to be working.

For example, if I declare

```
var array = [[String]]()
```

the app crashes when I try to append elements, like

```
array[1][0] = "Some string"
```

The only way I managed to make it work is by declaring the array with a fixed number of elements, but that's not good for my purpose.

I thought this was very easy to accomplish, but I encountered a lot of problems, any solution?

Comment: [You cannot append to an array with indices](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID110). You need to use the `append` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You cannot append to empty array like this `array[1][0] = "Some string"`. If you want to do that, you need to [create an array with certain size and repeated value](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107). But you want to create 2d-array, so that can be implemented like this:</s>

```
extension Array {
    static func bidimensional<T>(row: Int, _ column: Int, repeatedValue: T) -> [[T]] {
        var resultArray = [[T]]()
        for _ in 0...column {
            resultArray.append([T](count: row, repeatedValue: repeatedValue))
        }
        return resultArray
    }
}

var arr = [String].bidimensional(2, 2, repeatedValue: "")

arr[1][0] = "Hello there!"

print(arr[1][0]) // "Hello there!"
```

---

**Update**
[Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) add new functionality to an existing class, structure, or enumeration type. In our case we extend `Array` type with function `bidimensional`. The `static` means, that it's `type` method, not `instance` method. The `T` means, that it's [generic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179) method. In this case, you can call your `bidimensional` function not only with one specific type (like `String`), but any type you want (`String`, `Int`, `Double`, etc.). Well, the `bidimensional`'s func code is pretty simple. We just create empty 2D `resultArray` with our custom (`T`) type. Then we fill this array with our `repeatedValue` and return it. Thats all.
P.S. To be clear with generics there are several examples:

```
[Int].bidimensional(2, 2, repeatedValue: 0) // 2x2 with repeatedValue 0
[Double].bidimensional(5, 1, repeatedValue: 2.1) // 5x1 with repeatedValue 2.1

------ 

struct MyCustomStruct {
    var variable: String
}

var myCustomStruct = MyCustomStruct(variable: "repeat")

var arr = [MyCustomStruct].bidimensional(2, 2, repeatedValue: myCustomStruct)

print(arr[0][1].variable) // "repeat"
```

---

**Update 2 for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415321/data-structure-for-bidimensional-array/32415650#comment52716371_32415650).**

```
class MyClass {
    var arr = [[String]]()

    func fill2DArrayInLoop() {
        arr = [String].bidimensional(2, 2, repeatedValue: "")
        for i in 0...1 {
            for j in 0...1 {
                arr[i][j] = "row: \(i); col: \(j)"
            }
        }
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.fill2DArrayInLoop()
print(myClass.arr[0][1]) // "row: 0, col: 1"
```

---

Found the way to do this better ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127700/two-dimensional-array-in-swift/25128237#25128237)):

```
class MyClass {
    var arr = Array(count: 2, repeatedValue: Array(count: 2, repeatedValue: ""))

    func fill2DArrayInLoop() {
        for i in 0...1 {
            for j in 0...1 {
                arr[i][j] = "row: \(i); col: \(j)"
            }
        }
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.fill2DArrayInLoop()
print(myClass.arr[0][1]) // "row: 0, col: 1"
```

Now you don't need to create `extension`. Just put another declaration of array to `repeatedValue:` parameter.

Comment: You do not need to create an array of a certain size and repeated value to append to a multidimensional array. `var ar: [[Int]] = [[]]; ar[0].append(1)`.

Comment: @oisdk, @dpstar want to be able to add to array like this `arr[1][0] = "foo"`. You case doesn't support that.

Comment: `var ar: [[String]] = [[]]; ar.append(["foo"])`

Comment: The problem is that the array has to be created global for my class, and elements has to be added in a loop... how can I do that?

Comment: Thank you! @pacification

Comment: @dpstart, update my answer one more time :) Now you don't need an `extension` to create bidimensional array. You can do this in one line like this: `var arr = Array(count: 2, repeatedValue: Array(count: 2, repeatedValue: ""))`.