# Append array of arrays Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of arrays called Lines

```
Numbers = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

and `var numberInt = 10`

how do i append this `numberInt` inside the last array of the multidimensional array? so it would look like

```
Numbers = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: it doesn't look like you've tried anything. you should (especially since this is literally trivial.)

Comment: How about retrieving the last element in the array an appending the number to the retrieved array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Numbers[Numbers.count - 1]` to get last one-dimensional array and `append` method to add item:

```
Numbers[Numbers.count - 1].append(numberInt)
print(Numbers) // prints "[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]"
```

I'd also recommend you to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25128237/1796907

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant `Numbers.last ` is readonly property so I cannot use `append`

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant so not that trivial, right?)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Worked like a charm. I will study the link

Comment: @DavidRobertson "so not that trivial" – why not, exactly?

Comment: I'm with the Croissant. It's a trivial problem.