# Inserting a value into a matrix in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix

I wrote some code to insert a value along the diagonal of a matrix, but I can't figure out why it's giving me the error: `fatal error: Index out of range`

**The code:**

```
        var tempHamil = [[Double]]()
        var particleinboxHamil = [[Double]]()
        let boxlength: Double = LengthOfBox

        for i in 0...NumberEigenvalues-1{
            for j in 0...NumberEigenvalues-1{

                if i==j {

                    particleinboxHamil[i][j] = particleinboxenergy(ValueForN: i, LengthOfBox: box length)//error is thrown here

                } else {

                    particleinboxHamil[i][j]=0.0

                }

                tempHamil = particleinboxHamil

            }
        }
```

Comment: You are trying to assign values to empty arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Index out of range error is thrown when you try to access/write a value out of the arraybounds. In this case you are probably trying to write a value at `particleinboxHamil[i][j]` for a value i or j bigger than your array bounds.

`particleinboxHamil` is just an empty array (it is instantiated as such) and thus there is no `particleinboxHamil[i][j]` to write on.

Comment: Ok, so I need to instantiate...wait, is my notation even correct? I'm trying to make an `NxN` matrix, but I saw that matrices don't really exist in Swift, we only have these multi-dimensional arrays. Am I defining a *matrix* correctly in my code?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the following stackoverflow and/or google somewhat about 2d arrays in swift. Many people before you have conquered the issue you are facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127700/two-dimensional-array-in-swift

Comment: @loltospoon Or review the questions and answers used to close your question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to an empty array. Intialize it first

```
let emptyRow = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: NumberEigenvalues)
var tempHamil = [[Double]](repeating: emptyRow, count: NumberEigenvalues)
var particleinboxHamil = tempHamil
let boxlength: Double = LengthOfBox

for i in 0..<NumberEigenvalues {
    for j in 0..<NumberEigenvalues {

        if i == j {
            particleinboxHamil[i][j] = particleinboxenergy(ValueForN: i, LengthOfBox: box length)//error is thrown here

        }

        tempHamil = particleinboxHamil  // what's this for???
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post an answer to an already closed duplicate.