# Trivial 2D array locks up Xcode 9

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

This trivial piece of code in a Playground sets the Running wheel spinning forever, and it never prints output.  Other attempts to create a 2D array have led to an infinite Indexing loop in my real project.  I can't go to Xcode 10 due to my hardware being too old.  Has anyone got working code for 2D arrays?

```
import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"

var arr =  [[Int?]] ()
arr[1][2] = 17

print(str)
```

Comment: The code you posted should be causing a `Fatal error: Index out of range` since the arrays contain no elements and your trying to change one that doesn't exist.

Comment: yes in another attempt i saw that but this one can't even get that far!

Comment: `var arr: [[Int?]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: nil, count: 5), count: 5)` will give you a working 5x5 array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-dimensional array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127700/two-dimensional-array-in-swift)