# Swift: "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts" when attempting to retrieve Strings from a 2D array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

```
// 2D array
array = [["1", "lorem • ipsum", "other strings"], ["a","b","c"]] as NSArray

// label = UILabel // cell = dequeued cell from a collectionView
cell.label.text = array[1][0]
```

And after 'array[1][0]' an error is fetched by Xcode:

> Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts

Sorry, I might be missing something very trivial, but I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. I've checked other posts, but none seemed to fix this issue.

Comment: Don't use NSArray in swift, pretty much ever. It's not generic, so it doesn't know anything about its element besides that they exist, hence why they're considered an `Any`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `as NSArray` isn't helping you here and is confusing the compiler.  Taking `as NSArray` away makes the compiler realize you're trying to create an array of string arrays.

When I plug this code into a playground, it works:

```
// 2D array
let array = [["1", "lorem • ipsum", "other strings"], ["a","b","c"]]

let text = array[1][0]

Swift.print("text is \(text)")
```

and we get a result of "`a`", which is the zero'th element of the array in the 1st position.

More useful information [can be seen in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25127801).