# Swift 2D Array Performance

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift5

I am working on creating an iOS version of an Android app I created.  It involves a lot of two-dimensional array access and assignment, and it worked very quickly on Java.  However, when I converted to Swift, I noticed a very significant slowdown.  After some research on two dimensional Swift arrays, I thought the problem might be coming from the 2D arrays, so I decided to create and time a simple program to test 2D array performance.  I compared the execution times of a 2D and 1D array, and there was a significant difference.  Below is the program I used to test performance:

```
import Foundation

var numberOfItems = 1000
var myArray1 = [[Double]](repeating: [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: numberOfItems), count: numberOfItems)
var myArray2 = [[Double]](repeating: [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: numberOfItems), count: numberOfItems)
var myArray3 = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: numberOfItems * numberOfItems)
var myArray4 = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: numberOfItems * numberOfItems)

// 2D array assignment
let start1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
var x = 0.0
for i in 0..<numberOfItems {
    for j in 0..<numberOfItems {
        myArray1[i][j] = x
        x += 1
    }
}
let diff1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start1
print(diff1 * 1000)

// 2D array access and assignment
let start2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
for i in 0..<numberOfItems {
    for j in 0..<numberOfItems {
        myArray2[i][j] = myArray1[i][j]
    }
}
let diff2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start2
print(diff2 * 1000)

// 1D array assignment
var y = 0.0
let start3 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
for i in 0..<(numberOfItems * numberOfItems) {
    myArray3[i] = y
    y += 1
}
let diff3 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start3
print(diff3 * 1000)

// 1D array access and assignment
let start4 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
for i in 0..<(numberOfItems * numberOfItems) {
    myArray4[i] = myArray3[i]
}
let diff4 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start4
print(diff4 * 1000)
```

I ran it on the command line using the -Ounchecked option.  I got the following output (in ms, some variation but usually pretty close):

```
6.0759782791137695
24.2689847946167
2.4139881134033203
1.5819072723388672
```

Clearly there is a considerable performance difference between the 2D and 1D array implementations, especially when both accessing and assigning.

Is there a way to create a more efficient 2D array in Swift?  Performance is important for me in this instance, so is it better to use a 1D array and do some math for indexing?

Comment: It seems like you want a matrix, which can be implemented with 1D arrays, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53421491/5133585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to stick to a 2D array then you can use unsafe buffer pointers for faster access. However, 1D arrays are still going to be more efficient. Give this a shot.

```
    // 2D array assignment
    myArray1.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { outer1 -> Void in
        for i in 0..<numberOfItems {
            outer1[i].withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { inner1 -> Void in
                for j in 0..<numberOfItems {
                    inner1[j] = x
                    x += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // 2D array access and assignment
    myArray1.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { outer1 -> Void in
        myArray2.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { outer2 -> Void in
            for i in 0..<numberOfItems {
                outer1[i].withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { inner1 -> Void in
                    outer2[i].withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { inner2 -> Void in
                        for j in 0..<numberOfItems {
                            inner2[j] = inner1[j]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```