# Swift: Using TableView Sections with Array of Objects (Error: Value of type has no subscripts // Value of type has no member "count")

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, uitableview

I am running into a problem where I cannot find a solution and searching the web also doesn't help me.

The problem is pretty simple. I know how to make use of TableViews and also how to make use of the `numberOfSections` function.

The Problem now is, that I am retrieving Data from Firebase Database as an Array of Objects.
Here it is `members = [PaymentTeam]()` where the class looks like this:

```
class PaymentTeam {
    
    var key: String?
    let memberJob: String?
    let memberName: String?
    let memberID:String?
    let projectCreated:String?
    let projectName: String?
    let confirmedBool: Bool?
    let paidBool: Bool?
        
    
    init(memberJob: String, memberName: String, memberID:String, confirmedBool: Bool, paidBool: Bool, projectCreated:String, projectName: String) {
            

        self.memberName = memberName
        self.memberJob = memberJob
        self.memberID = memberID
        self.projectCreated = projectCreated
        self.confirmedBool = confirmedBool
        self.paidBool = paidBool
        self.projectName = projectName
        }
    
    
    var dictValue: [String: Any] {
        
        return ["memberName" : memberName as Any,
                "memberJob" : memberJob as Any,
                "memberID": memberID as Any,
                "projectCreated": projectCreated as Any,
                "confirmedBool": confirmedBool as Any,
                "paidBool": paidBool as Any,
                "projectName": projectName as Any
                ]
        

    }
    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary,
            
            let memberJob = dict["memberJob"] as? String,
            let memberName = dict["memberName"] as? String,
            let projectCreated = dict["projectCreated"] as? String,
            let projectName = dict["projectName"] as? String,
            let memberID = dict["memberID"] as? String,
            let confirmedBool = dict["confirmedBool"] as? Bool,
            let paidBool = dict["paidBool"] as? Bool
       
            else {return nil}
                         self.memberJob = memberJob
                         self.memberName = memberName
                         self.projectCreated = projectCreated
                         self.projectName = projectName
                         self.memberID = memberID
                         self.confirmedBool = confirmedBool
                         self.paidBool = paidBool
    }
    
}
```

and retrieving is done like this:

```
   static func chosenTeam(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([PaymentTeam]) -> Void) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("selectedTeams").child(User.current.uid)
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
                return completion([])
            }
            let chosenTeam = snapshot.reversed().compactMap(PaymentTeam.init)
            completion(chosenTeam)
        })
    }
```

The problem now is, that with:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return members[section].count
      
        }
```

I get the error message: `Value of type 'PaymentTeam' has no member 'count'` and I can only choose between the different class members like `members.memberID`

For the function:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            let member = members[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChosenTeamNameTableViewCell") as! ChosenTeamNameTableViewCell
            cell.memberNameLabel.text = member.memberName
            
            return cell
            }
```

I get following error message:

```
Value of type 'PaymentTeam' has no subscripts
```

Whereby `[indexPath.section]`is underlined.

Maybe someone can help me to figure out how to structure my Firebase Data in that `members`Array to actually make use of `numberofSections`

Here is the whole code for the ViewController with the Tableview:

```
class PaymentHomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerSeperator: UIView!
    
        
   
    var members = [PaymentTeam]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            setUpUI()
            
            UserService.chosenTeam(for: User.current) { (chosenTeam) in
                self.members = chosenTeam
                for value in self.members {
                    self.projectTitles.append(value.projectName ?? "Error")
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        

    func setUpUI() {
        Utilities.addShadowtoView(headerSeperator)
    }

 extension PaymentHomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

          
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "Header"
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
        
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return members.count
          }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return members[section].count
      
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            let member = members[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChosenTeamNameTableViewCell") as! ChosenTeamNameTableViewCell
            cell.memberNameLabel.text = member.memberName
            
            return cell
            }
        }


    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

    extension PaymentHomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
         return 78
            
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `numberOfRowsInSection`, you're unintentionally attempting to access a member called "count" of type "PaymentTeam" here:

```
return members[section].count
```

"members" is a one-dimensional array, so, `members[section]` is returning an object of type `PaymentTeam`, which is not an array and therefore will not have a count. Change it to:

```
return members.count
```

Now, your second error arises at this line:

```
let member = members[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Again, "members" is a one-dimensional array, not two-dimensional. You're trying to access a member of a two-dimensional array with `array[index1][index2]`. This doesn't make sense as `PaymentTeam` is not an array. You can find some more information about two-dimensional arrays in swift in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127700/two-dimensional-array-in-swift) StackOverflow thread. Change this to:

```
let member = members[indexPath.row]
```